# MongoDB c# find() returns an objectid for the _id but it's a string in the document

Tags: c#, mongodb, objectid

I inherited this MongoDB which is used as a Cache of sorts. The _id of all documents in the collection are strings such as:

```
_someCommonLibraryName.ConnectorLib_2016_2_0.InventoryItem:MODERN CATCH 8 ATGR+ HCP
```

(Yes that's the _id.)

The issue seems to be with any _ids with a plus symbol in them.

When I query the collection like so:

```
var proj = new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>().Include("_id").Include("internalId");
var findFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(
               Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("recordType", itemName),
               Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("internalId"),
               Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Not(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Type("internalId", BsonType.Null)),
               Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("success", true)
               );

objsWithInternalId = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(findFilter).Project(proj).ToEnumerable();
```

I get back an ObjectID for the _id field only for a small subset of results (all of which have plus symbols in the _id). All of the _ids without a plus symbol are strings.

I will attempt to get them to allow me to change the documents so that the long string is made into a field and allow all the _ids to be ObjectIds, but in the meantime I would like to figure out what I can do to get the string result for ALL _ids.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh and if I look up these offending documents in say Robo 3T the document is fine and the _id is a string.

Comment: What is internalId?

Comment: internalId is a field in the document. It is a string. 

the important fields in the document are: internalId, recordType, lastTouched (date), _id and data (xml)

Everything is a string except the ones I qualified.

Comment: So your code somehow converts "_someCommonLibraryName.ConnectorLib_2016_2_0.InventoryItem:MODERN CATCH 8 ATGR+ HCP
" to an objectId, right?

Comment: That's what is happening, but only if the _id has a +. 
"_someCommonLibraryName.ConnectorLib_2016_2_0.InventoryItem:MODERN CATCH 8 ATGR+ HCP " returns "5b37965faa8590c308ba2700"   and "_someCommonLibraryName.ConnectorLib_2016_2_0.InventoryItem:MODERN PUT 350 TOUR 5 " returns "_someCommonLibraryName.ConnectorLib_2016_2_0.InventoryItem:MODERN PUT 350 TOUR 5 "

Comment: Have you tried creating a class out of your document (instead of BsonDocument) and also using something other than `ToEnumerable()`? I cannot repro the exact issue but I see some weird things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mahdi but it doesn't work. The issue must be on the server. 
Error: 
    An error occurred while deserializing the ID property of class netsuite_unified_sync.sources.MongoSource+CacheQueryResult: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.

From:
    List<CacheQueryResult> objsWithInternalId =  cacheCollection.Find<CacheQueryResult>(findFilter).Project<CacheQueryResult>("{_id: 1, internalId: 1, recordType: 1 }").ToList();

Comment: Also Tried: var objsWithInternalId = cacheCollection.Find(x => x.recordType == itemName && x.internalId != null)
                .Project<CacheQueryResult>("{ _id: 1, internalId: 1, recordType: 1 }").ToList();

Same problem

Comment: Just updated the driver to 2.7.0. Don't know what else to try.